# rosbridge questions

Tags: rosbridge, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am kinda new to ROS here. I'm confused as to how rosjs works, it specified in the tutorial that I need to run rosbridge, but since I am currently running on windows, is it possible to get the package via SVN checkout or apt-get repository?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35418/rosbridge-questions/) by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Here you will find the svn adress http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distribution/brown_remotelab/rosbridge

For more information on this package, take a loof to http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbridge

---

Originally posted by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) with karma: 56 on 2012-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) on 2012-06-03**:
Thanks BeuBeu! One other tip: uf you're running on windows, you probably want to use the "nightly" or experimental version at: http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/rosbridge . How exactly you download it via SVN will depend on your client.

**Comment by [tjay](https://answers.ros.org/users/502/tjay/) on 2012-06-03**:
Oh and I should of course point out that you can run rosbridge on a non-windows machine and do your JS stuff on the Windows machine or anywhere else.

**Comment by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on 2012-06-03**:
Thanks for the replies. I managed to download the package with TortoiseSVN. Gonna try going through the tutorials on how to install the package.

If it is still impossible, I might give the second method a try.

**Comment by [BeuBeu](https://answers.ros.org/users/329/beubeu/) on 2012-06-04**:
I hope you will suceed because rosbridge is really amazing :)

**Comment by [RJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/2492/rj/) on 2012-06-04**:
So, I encountered this -

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/experimental/rosbridge': could not connect to server (http://brown-ros-pkg.googlecode.com) while trying to get the package in Ubuntu.

Any help?

Okay, managed to solve it because of a proxy problem.